# Can you cap the amount of messages that can be sent in a given time period in Twilio?

Tags: security, twilio, sms, auth-token

I want to self impose a SMS limit per month in Twilio. I see this as a safeguard in the event that my Authorization Token is compromised somehow. That way only so messages would be able to be sent before getting cut off. Is there a way to do this in your account?

I have browsed some help docs but haven't found the solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to limit the number of messages you can sent yourself.
However, you can get the number of messages sent and other types of using the [Usage Records API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api/usage-record).
You could develop an integration that will notify you based on what is returned from the API.